# DS3231 AT24C32 IIC making digital outputs not work

Tags: shift-register

I have just taken the code from

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ds3231-precision-rtc-breakout/wiring-and-test

to get DS3231 AT24C32 IIC to work fine with my Aduino and its working fine.

I have then taken
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-4-eight-leds 
and expanded it to work with three 74HC595 Shift Register. And this is working fine with all three sets of LEDS lighting up one after an other like in the demo.

So I do not think there is anything wrong with my wiring.

When I merge the two demos together, all the output pins on my this shirt register just give out positive current constantly.

I have walked through each line of the code and the problem is caused by

```
if (! rtc.begin()) {
```

if I take out that if statement everything works.  But since that is the bit that starts the clock I want that.

So how do I get the DS3231 started and not have all the pins on the third shift register high?

Also if it matter it is an official Leonardo board.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

int latchPinOne = 5; 
int clockPinOne = 6; 
int dataPinOne = 4; 

int latchPinTwo = 11; 
int clockPinTwo = 10; 
int dataPinTwo = 8; 

int latchPinThree = 3; 
int clockPinThree = 13; 
int dataPinThree = 2; 

byte leds = 0;

void setup()
{
#ifndef ESP8266
  while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
#endif

  pinMode(dataPinOne, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPinOne, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPinOne, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(dataPinTwo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPinTwo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPinTwo, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(dataPinThree, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPinThree, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPinThree, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Start");

  delay(3000); // wait for console opening
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  leds = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    bitSet(leds, i);
    updateShiftRegister();
    delay(500);
  }
}

void updateShiftRegister()
{

  digitalWrite(latchPinOne, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPinOne, clockPinOne, LSBFIRST, leds); // send the data
  digitalWrite(latchPinOne, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(latchPinTwo, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPinTwo, clockPinTwo, LSBFIRST, leds); // send the data
  digitalWrite(latchPinTwo, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(latchPinThree, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPinThree, clockPinThree, LSBFIRST, leds); // send the data
  digitalWrite(latchPinThree, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Check for pin conflicts. What pins are used for the RTC? SDA and SCL but they are also pins 2 and 3. Opps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a classical case of pin conflicts when merging several sketches.

In this case it is hidden by the fact that TWI SDA and SCL are separate pins on the [Arduino Leonardo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/arduinoBoardLeonardo). But they are also connected to pins 2 and 3 (not A4 and A5 as on Arduino Uno).

Selecting other pins (latch/data) for the third shift register should help.

Cheers.

Comment: It was the fact I was using Pin 2 And 3 for output.  I didn't know that the SCL and SDA were connecting Pin 2 and 3.  I Changed it to Pin 7 and 9, and everything worked.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail